# read column of a text file using loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

Hii i have a text file that contain 3 columns, in each iteration i want to read one column

```
2 3 4
2 3 4
2 1 3
4 5 6
3 5 2
```

in first iteration i need to read first column values`[2 2 2 4 3]` then second column and so on  and want to save it in any name

i tried script

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('inpfile')
for col in range(data[1]:
    print(data[:,col])
```

but it doesnot read column by column instead it gives whole data as output.can anybody suggest a better solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Your requirement can be fulfilled by a library called pandas.

the function is called pandas.read_csv please use the following example

```
data = pd.read_csv('output_list.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "etc."]
```

[more about the function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#:%7E:text=Read%20a%20comma%2Dseparated%20values,online%20docs%20for%20IO%20Tools.)

Comment: You are welcome.. You can pick columns by using data[[‘column1’,’column2’]] this notation